# What is the equivalent name for a compilation unit for a transpiler?

Tags: compilation, terminology, transpiler

I am planning out a transpiler that transpiles code to Lua. I honestly don't know what to call my compilation units. Should I call them transpilation units? Translation units? I guess I am just looking for the proper name for a compilation unit in a transpiler. Maybe there isn't a name, :P. I guess this is just a sanity check, :).

Answer (score 1):

Transpiling is converting source code from one language to another. It's like translating a book from English to French. You're not compiling code, as much as you're translating it.

The term you are probably looking for is *token*. A program's source is made up of tokens, the individual units of code. Tokens consist of keywords, identifiers, operators, etc.

For reference:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Token